# Usage of ports for Socket.io with Wamp-server

Tags: javascript, socket.io, wampserver

I am new to websocket and I installed WampServer (I am using it on port 81) to use it for my localhost hosting and run some code from Phaser.js . Now, I want to make a multiplayer game and I tried to use Socket.io, but what port do I need to use if I use 81 for WampServer?

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/) can use any port, here is sample code:

```
    const server = require('http').createServer();

    const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
      path: '/test',
      serveClient: false,
      // below are engine.IO options
      pingInterval: 10000,
      pingTimeout: 5000,
      cookie: false
    });
```

To use wamp server with socket.io check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859633/making-socket-io-work-from-localhost-through-wamp-server) out.

Comment: But in my Web Browser (if I use 3000 as your example for Socket.io), I need localhost:81 to acces Wamp, so how do I reach port 3000?